# Need help with doing a hyperbolic trigonometry problem.

Tags: trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

If $x=2\cos(\alpha)\cosh(\beta)$ and $y=2\sin(\alpha)\sinh(\beta)$, prove: $$\sec(\alpha+i\beta)+\sec(\alpha-i\beta)=\frac{4x}{(x^2+y^2)}$$
I had an incorrect equation. The iota was missing.

Comment: I believe that the problem is written incorrectly. Plugging in $\alpha=1,\beta=1$ into the L.H.S. gives $\sec(2)\approx-1.403$, and plugging it into the R.H.S. gives $\frac{4x}{x^2+y^2}\approx0.997$.

Comment: @ThePretzelMan indeed, I have been trying hard to solve an incorrect equation.

Answer (score 4):

$$\sec(\alpha+i\beta)+\sec(\alpha-i\beta)$$
$$\frac{1}{\cos(\alpha+i\beta)}+\frac{1}{\cos(\alpha-i\beta)}$$
$$\frac{2\cos(\alpha)\cos(i\beta)}{(\cos(\alpha)\cos(i\beta))^2-(\sin(\alpha)\sin(i\beta))^2}$$
$$\frac{\frac{x}{\cosh(\beta)}\cosh(\beta)}{(\frac{x}{2\cosh(\beta)}\cosh(\beta))^2-(\frac{y}{2\sinh(\beta)}i\sinh(\beta))^2}$$
$$\frac{4x}{x^2+y^2}$$

Comment: nice answer................+1